# Does CREATE OR REPLACE statement affect time travel in snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

If I create a table in snowflake and then create another one with the same name using CREATE OR REPLACE statement, I am not able to access the content of the first table using time travel.

For example, if I run this code

```
CREATE TABLE "MY_DB"."MY_SCHEMA"."MY_TABLE" (COL1 VARCHAR, COL2 NUMBER);   
INSERT INTO "MY_DB"."MY_SCHEMA"."MY_TABLE" VALUES ('A',1);
```

... and then in five minutes run this chunk of code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE "MY_DB"."MY_SCHEMA"."MY_TABLE" (COL1 VARCHAR, COL2 NUMBER);
INSERT INTO "MY_DB"."MY_SCHEMA"."MY_TABLE" VALUES ('B',2);
SELECT * FROM "MY_DB"."MY_SCHEMA"."MY_TABLE"
UNION
SELECT * FROM "MY_DB"."MY_SCHEMA"."MY_TABLE" AT (offset => -60*1)
```

The query only returns the values from the second table. Is this behavior expected? I tried to google this or find clarification in snowflake documentation without any luck...

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes - this is expected.  By running a CREATE OR REPLACE, you've dropped the original table and replaced it with a new table.  There will be no time-travel data from before the replace table was issued.

If you wish to remove the data from a table and retain the data for time-travel purposes, leverage a `TRUNCATE TABLE` statement, instead.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/truncate-table.html

Comment: There's also `insert overwrite` -- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/insert.html#insert-using-overwrite

Answer (score 12):

Update: See @peterb answer "restore the old table by using [time travel at the schema level](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66576724/132438)"

---

As Mike says, the previous table was dropped with the `CREATE AND REPLACE`, so time travel won't be able to find it.

Nevertheless, you can still recover the data by renaming the newer table, and undropping the previous one:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "test_travel" (COL1 VARCHAR, COL2 NUMBER);   
INSERT INTO "test_travel" VALUES ('A',1);

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE "test_travel" (COL1 VARCHAR, COL2 NUMBER);   
INSERT INTO "test_travel" VALUES ('B',2);

ALTER TABLE "test_travel" RENAME TO "test_travel2";

UNDROP TABLE "test_travel";

SELECT *
FROM "test_travel" AT (offset => -60*1)
```

[image]

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-time-travel.html#restoring-objects

Comment: I'm glad this was helpful! Please remember to upvote and/or accept answers that have been useful to you

Answer (score 8):

You can also restore the old table by using time travel at the schema level to the time before you ran Create or Replace Table:

```
create schema "MY_DB"."MY_SCHEMA_RESTORED" clone "MY_DB"."MY_SCHEMA" AT (offset => -60*1)
```

Comment: oh, I love this approach