# snowflake Time travel data is not available

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I accidently recreated a table on snowflake (LICENCE_TEST), when I try to flashback the table using accountadmin/superuser role

```
CREATE  TABLE LICENCE_TEST2
CLONE LICENCE_TEST before (TIMESTAMP => to_timestamp_ntz('2021-07-01 11:03:00'))
```

I received error message:

```
Time travel data is not available for table LICENCE_TEST. The requested time is either beyond the allowed time travel period or before the object creation time.
```

from the TABLE_STORAGE_METRICS, it clearly shows the table data is still available and is it no a transit table
[image]

Does anyone know why?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you dropped and re-created the table. If you want to get the table back you need to `UNDROP` it first. You'll need to rename the current `LICENCE_TEST` table to something else so that the table can be brought back. From [this part](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-time-travel.html#restoring-objects) of the documentation:

> If an object with the same name already exists, UNDROP fails. You must rename the existing object, which then enables you to restore the previous version of the object.

Try something like:

```sql
alter table LICENSE_TEST rename to LICENSE_TEST_1;
UNDROP TABLE LICENSE_TEST;
```

You can keep renaming / undropping like this until the timetravel retention period is over I think.

Comment: if table was dropped / re-created a lot, you can use time travel at the schema level to recover the table at the point in time you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66576724/12502175